# get updated query in nuxt plugin after page load

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js

Well, I have a plugin with some functions in it, functions should update URL queries.
The problem is, everytime I execute `$global.changePage(2)` or `$global.changeLimit(2)` the `console.log(query)` returns an empty object and didn't return updated queries in URL.

I know NuxtJS plugins execute once we load the page but is there any way to have updated `query` each time I use those functions?

```js
export default (ctx: NuxtConfig, inject: Inject) => {
  const { app, query } = ctx;

  const global = {
    changePage (page: number) {
      console.log(query);
      
      app.router.push({
        query: { ...query, page }
      })
    },

    changeLimit(limit: number) {
      console.log(query);

      app.router.push({
        query: { ...query, limit }
      })
    },
  }

  inject('global', global)
  ctx.$global = global
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `ctx.$global = global` from the last line of your plugin.

The `inject` method provided by Nuxt takes care of making your `global` object available where it's needed, so there's really no need for you to overwrite the ctx.$global property.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. do you have any solution for getting dynamic queries problem?

Comment: Sure, I think I can see what's going wrong but I'd be able to help you better if you could give more information. Where are you calling your methods, what are you expecting to happen, what is happening? Are you using Nuxt in SPA mode, SSR, etc?